# Where is the code for the ticketing system of DiscV5?

Tags: node-discovery, devp2p, discovery-protocol

So my understanding from several sources is that discV5 has a [ticketing mechanism for security](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/discv5/discv5-theory.md#advertisement-protocol).

I went to the `go-ethereum` code to inspect the code. I was unable to find it...
The best I could find was [reserved constants for the message types](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/p2p/discover/v5wire/msg.go#L50-L51)

But I can't find that those message types are used or any other ticketing logic...
Can someone please help?

Thanks!